# in vue In the Vue, the first kind of writing is correct, and the second kind of writing is wrong，why？

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
{{str.split('').reverse().join()}}
{{arr.reverse().join()}}
```

This ERROR is shown while writing the second line.

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

Comment: `arr.reverse()` reverses the array in place ... what if you `{{arr.slice().reverse().join()}}`

Comment: Are you using any render function of Vue?

Answer (score 1):

You must be in render a method, for e.g. rendering the list of item using some state value.
**NOTE**: render method is triggered whenever any state changes.
Also, since you are using Vue, take full advantage of Vue's **computed** property:

```
computed: {
 yourComputedFunction: function() {
   return arr.slice().reverse().join();
 }
}
```

In your **HTML**: `{{yourComputedFunction}}`